# Split text expanding rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```py
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'source':['a','b','a','b'],
                     'text':['November rain','Sweet child omine','Paradise City','Patience']})
mydf

    source  text
0   a       November rain
1   b       Sweet child omine
2   a       Paradise City
3   b       Patience
```

And I want to split the text inside column `text`. This is the expected result:

```py
    source  text
0   a       November 
1   a       rain
2   b       Sweet 
3   b       child 
4   b       omine
5   a       Paradise 
6   a       City
7   b       Patience
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
mydf['text'] = mydf['text'].str.split(expand=True)
```

But it returns me an error:

```py
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there a way to do this without creating an index?

Comment: Ye, as Quang Hoang said, you're looking for `explode`, not `expand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.split(expand=True)` returns a dataframe, normally with more than one column, so you can't assign back to your original column:

```
# output of `str.split(expand=True)`
          0      1      2
0  November   rain   None
1     Sweet  child  omine
2  Paradise   City   None
3  Patience   None   None
```

I think you mean:

```
# expand=False is default
mydf['text'] = mydf['text'].str.split()
mydf = mydf.explode('text')
```

You can also chain with `assign`:

```
mydf.assign(text=mydf['text'].str.split()).explode('text')
```

Output:

```
  source      text
0      a  November
0      a      rain
1      b     Sweet
1      b     child
1      b     omine
2      a  Paradise
2      a      City
3      b  Patience
```

Comment: Exactly the answer that I needed!, It works fine! Thanks @Quang Hoang